# Display percentage change in the title of Highcharts timeseries

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a use case where I need to display the percentage change in value of a time series chart in the chart title.

So far, I have tried getting the first and last element of the series, but this only works when all the data is visible. I need a way to account for the zoom buttons and the range selector elements.

Any suggestions on how to obtain the first and last axis y values of the current date range?

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL price change +5%' // how to get the %?
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }], 
        });
    });
});
```

Edit: I have tried to adapt another example to my needs: http://jsfiddle.net/F8MjD/5/

Example used: http://jsfiddle.net/NsD3s/7/

But still doesn't work, even though it looks exactly the same to me?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from min and max on yAxis.

```
 chart:{
            events:{
                redraw:function(){
                    var axis = this.yAxis[0];

                    $('#report').html('Min: ' + axis.max+ ' Max: '+ axis.min);

                }
            }

        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8MjD/4/

Comment: Thanks for the response! But that doesn't appear to show the first and last visible values though. For instance, for the 3m range, I see: `Min: 580 Max: 460`, yet the first visible point clearly is 489.56 and the last is 553.13 (ignoring the fact that you've accidentally flipped min and max in the jsFiddle).

Comment: Min/max returns a value on yAxis, not y from serie. If you would like to get y value, you need to catch setExtremes and then iterate on each point form serie and check x value. if it is the same then return to "report".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. All I need is the first and last visible Y axis values on the chart. Is there no way to get it?

Comment: My use case is very simple. Take the first and last *currently visible* value, calculate the difference, put it in a title. axis.min and max only show me the highest and lowest values within the range which is completely different.

Comment: I mean, catch setExtremes, save minX and maxY (from xAxis), use loop on series data and check if minX or maxY is the point.

Comment: OK, say I have `event.min` and `event.max` and this.series[0].data. How do I actually iterate over that object?

Comment: You can use loop, like $.each() or for or other.

Comment: $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(key,item) {
  alert(item);
 }); alerts undefined 2000 times